# How to capitalize first letter each word binded via ng-model

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a api returned json which i am binding to a form elements via ng model

the returned data from api is in UPPERCASE, how can i apply filter / css? to get each first letter in all words to be capital

```html
<input type = text ng-model = string>
```

need to make this string binded by the value(obtained via API) in controller to be in camel case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize fields in a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784252/capitalize-fields-in-a-form)

Comment: text-transform: capitalize;

Comment: @SahilDhir `text-transform: capitalize;` won't work with uppercase text see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7jjapjvp/)

Comment: @AbhishekPandey my bad I din't read the question carefully.

Comment: @SanjanaHE Have you tried my answer?

Comment: tried your answer @AbhishekPandey thanks..works for my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use angular's `lowercase` filter and then transform text with css.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.string = 'LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, DUIS VIDIT DEFINITIONES MEL NE'
});
```

```css
input {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app=myApp ng-controller=myCtrl>
  <input type=text ng-model="string | lowercase" >
</div>
```

Comment: One issue im facing with this approach [link]https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign?p0=profile.st%20%7C%20lowercase&p1=%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20class%3D any idea how to resolve?

Comment: I don't have much idea about this error, filter is still working even with error that's the strange thing, may be you can ask another question with this error.

Comment: resolved the issue by replacing ng-model with value={{string | lowercase}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution.

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
 app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.msg = 'hello, world.';
  });

app.filter('capitalize', function() {
   return function(input) {
     return (!!input) ? input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
     input.substr(1).toLowerCase() : '';
  }
});
```

view must be like this

```
<p><b>My Text:</b> {{msg | capitalize}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vanilla JavaScript solution:

```
function capitalize(str){
    if(!str || typeof str !== 'string')
        return ""

    var newString = str; 
    var firstLetter = str[0];
    newString = newString.toLowerCase().slice(1, newString.length);

    return [firstLetter, newString].join('');
}
```

Otherwise you can use an AngularJS filter

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .filter('capitalize', capitalize)
```

Where `capitalize` is the very same function I have written above. This gives you ability to use this directly in the view:

```
<span>{{::vm.value | capitalize}}</span>
```